# Citations are chapter specific - Tufte-book

Tags: citing, tufte

I'm relatively new to LaTeX and fighting a loosing battle here! I'm building my thesis in the tufte style presented by Overleaf.com. I love the look of it, but it is doing things that defy logic to me. 
So my "current" biggest issue is that for every chapter I write, I include citations of papers which beautifully align in the margin, but they are numbered wrong.

So in chapter 1 I may have 5 citations.
They are labelled {1,2,3,4,5}
Then in chapter 2 I may have 3 citations.
They are labelled {1,2,3}.

Thats a problem! No citation should ever have the same number. They should be unique!

This is by using `\cite{}`

If I use `\citep{}` They are correct and show the number linked in the reference collection (References.bib). However using the `\citep` looks ugly, the reference no longer shows up in the margin and in some cases it shoots the actual text into the margin.

It's slightly difficult for me to post the code here, as I don't know whats going on. Its a default document setting when you start a tufte-style book template in overleaf.

Any suggestions to what I can do or what I could post to assist? [image]

Here is a snippet where the main text is seen on the left and the `\cite{}` are seen to the right. The numbers 3,4 and 5 should correspond to the correct numbers from the reference section where they are 7,4 and 11.

Thank you for your time. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)

Comment: @DG' I'm not sure how to do that. Cause its a large file with several support files. H owever if you go to this link, the template and the entire source code is there.
https://da.overleaf.com/latex/templates/book-design-inspired-by-edward-tufte/gcfbtdjfqdjh
I believe its the auxillary file named tufte-common.def that holds the key to this solution.

Comment: Just make up a small compilable document with bibliography, that exhibits the behavior in question. Without code there is nothing we can do.